# Matlab returns license checkout error when executed from Wamp server but not command prompt

Tags: php, matlab, licensing, wamp

I am running WAMP Server 2.5 (32-bit) with PHP 5.5.12 on a Windows 7 SP1 64-bit machine. I am running Matlab R2014b.

I am trying to execute Matlab via PHP.

The Matlab function phptest.m is as follow:

```
function phptest
% Open file
fid = fopen('success.txt', 'wt');
%Print a test string
fprintf(fid, 'Test matlab function');
% Close file
fclose(fid);
% Quit MATLAB
quit force
```

When I execute from the command prompt:

```
matlab -wait -nosplash -sd "C:\wamp\www\testMatlab" -logfile logfile.txt -r "phptest;"
```

the code runs without problems and the file 'sucess.txt' is created.

However, if I try to execute via a php file:

```
<?php
$testStr = 'matlab -wait -nosplash -sd "C:\wamp\www\testMatlab" -logfile logfile.txt -r "phptest;"';
exec($testStr);
echo("Done!");
?>
```

The logfile shows the following error:

Severe:
Error checking out license

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force MATLAB to use a specific license file by running it with the `-c` flag:

```
'matlab -c "path/to/license" -wait -nosplash -sd "C:\wamp\www\testMatlab" -logfile logfile.txt -r "phptest;"';
```

> matlab -c licensefile starts MATLAB using the specified license file.
>   The licensefile argument can have the form port@host or it can be a
>   colon-separated list of license filenames. This option causes the
>   LM_LICENSE_FILE and MLM_LICENSE_FILE environment variables to be
>   ignored.

See: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html

Comment: Thank you. The "-c" option seems to have solved the license checkout error, however, now the php page hangs in the browser. If I execute the same command (with the -c option) in the command prompt it still executes perfectly. Really baffled!

Comment: If you don't need the output of your script, you can execute your script in the background; http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
Also, check that your function is within the search path or startup folder of MATLAB.
You specify -sd, but this option has been deprecated. Please check: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_env/matlab-startup-folder.html